# use quotation marks within R's paste function

Tags: r

I try to use `as.formula()` together with `paste()` to build a regression equation.

The follwoing example works well: `as.formula(paste("y ~ 1 + x1 +", paste("y", 2, sep=""), sep=""))`.

However, how to use quotation marks within `paste()`? This line fails: `as.formula(paste("y ~ 1 + x1 + fx(x2, m="abc")", paste("y", 2, sep=""), sep=""))`. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Like this: `m = 'abc'`

Comment: Or you can escape the double quotes like this: `m=\"abc\"`.